potentiometer volume control of backup beeper
Total newbie here.  Please bear with me.
I am interested in making a gag gift for a friend, which uses a typical audio mixer slider to control the volume of a typical backup beeper.
This is Not intended for use in a vehicle. In my mind’s eye, it’s a small, nice, tasteful little box, with the slider on top, and a suitable beeper and (preferably) with its own battery hidden inside.
If I buy a typical backup beeper (ecco 500, for example), and a typical mixer slider (uxcell variable fader, for example), would the wiring be a simple thing? Like splicing the fader between wires to the beeper’s speaker? Or putting the fader in line with the power to the beeper?
Also, the beeper is 12v. Any chance of a battery smaller than a heavy car battery to make this work?
Again, it’s a gag gift. It should look nice, and be self-contained, preferably without plugging it into wall power.


The siren is rated for at least 100mA and 12V. Even if 10 AA batteries could work, the fader can't directly control the sound level by changing voltage to siren, and the siren likely won't change the sound level by much if you vary the voltage. Why not consider a different approach with a tone generator, amplifier and speaker, where the fader can control the amplifier output level.

Glad to consider a more reasonable approach, designed to specs from scratch.  I'm just wondering if off-the-shelf purchases get me close.  Sounds like probably not.

There's a lot of different modules intended for hobbyists to buy. However it would be off-topic to ask here what to buy and from where. The modules also mostly come with no data sheet, manual or instructions how to use them, so you  really need some level of understanding what to buy and how to connect them. Also, having such an automotive siren that's capable of causing permanent hearing damage nearby you might not be a fun gag.

A better approach is to buy a module that records and plays back sounds. Go to Amazon and search for recordable greeting card module

Great suggestions. This proposed idea is kinda funny as a concept, maybe funny once, and not so smart in the long run. Didn’t know about recordable greeting cards … that’s the ticket. Thanks.
